Horror movie with a child's drawing of a blue sun
I remember watching a scene from a (probably) horror movie on TV many years ago. In it, a man is asking a young boy what he's drawing and the boy describes the picture. And then the guy points at the drawing of the sun (which is in blue) and asks what that is and the kid says "That's the blue sun" or something like that.
It's not that old, I saw it in the 90s. Definitely color and most probably American actors but I saw it dubbed in my language so I can't say but I'm pretty sure it was a Hollywood flick
Any ideas?

Do you think you could elaborate a little please. What language? American actors or maybe British? Colour or b&w? You saw it many years ago.. 70's 80's? Did it seem new then? Anything to narrow it down a little

Oh, right. It's not that old, I saw it in the 90s. Definitely color and most probably American actors but I saw it dubbed in my language so I can't say but I'm pretty sure it was a Hollywood flick

I don't know if this scene is enough to go on. If it's not pivotal or memorable but rather a random scene you remembered (and definitely if it happens to be from a less-known film), you might have to wait for someone who saw this film too and still remembers all of it clearly. So do you remember any other plot detail, scene or characters?

There is an horror movie, from the late '70s, called "Blue Sunshine", but I don't know if it can be your title. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0074226/

Stumbled across a good match: There's an identical scene in The Crow: City of Angels from 1996 where the hero (Ashe) and his 8 year old son are killed by thugs; right before that, his son draws a blue sun. Ashe asks him what it is and the son replies, "That's the blue sun". Ashe is resurrected later on. You can see the scene here:



